# PHP classes and extended classes into 1 variable

Tags: php, class

I have an issue I am facing with PHP classes.

I need to do this:

```
class main{
    function something(){

        echo 'something';
    }
}

class second extends main{

    function something_else(){
        echo 'something else';
    }
}

class third extends main{
    function something_else_two(){
        echo 'something else two';
    }
}

$var = new main;
$var->something_else();
$var-something_else_two();
```

The extended classes are being loaded depending one the files being ina  certain folder, so it could load endless amount if them class files exist, the class files will always extend MAIN.

So my question is how can I get the values for each class into one variable so I can use it anywhere?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't. A class extends only 1 other class (which may extend another class, etc.). You can do _some_ work with implementing Interfaces, and Traits, but be very sure you need it: the need for a `Trait` usually means you've got your design wrong (exceptions are possible but rare).

Comment: What you probably are more likely to want: a `Factory` method, which gives you an instance of _some_ class which extends `main`, by whatever logic you deem necessary, but that would mean you should _only_ use methods on it that are defined in the `main` class, as that is it's contract with the outside world. _Internally_, those methods could call non-main methods (`class  second extends main { function something(){ echo 'something'; $this->something_else();}..`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I didn't explain myself correctly. basically all the class files are in one folder. The file names are the same as the class names. I need to loop through all these files and make the class functions/variable into one object cass so I can define them anywhere using the one variable. Thanks for your help.